# Groupby first start date

Tags: python, python-3.x, grouping, pandas-groupby

my problem is the following I have this dataframe and I would like to sort of groupby by week_nb and year_nb. For example the final result would look something like: (I didn't make the calculation for hour_duration for year nb 2018 and 2019)

[image]

Where we always keep the first "start_date" of the week_nb and year_nb and we sum all the hour_duration

You can find below the partial dataframe, because in the full dataset there as well week_nb = 2, 3 ... with the corresponding year

[image]

```
{'week_nb': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 1,
  7: 1,
  8: 1,
  9: 1,
  10: 1,
  11: 1,
  12: 1,
  13: 1,
  14: 1,
  15: 1,
  16: 1,
  17: 1,
  18: 1,
  19: 1,
  20: 1,
  21: 1,
  22: 1,
  23: 1,
  24: 1,
  25: 1,
  26: 1,
  27: 1,
  28: 2,
  29: 2,
  30: 2,
  31: 2,
  32: 2,
  33: 2,
  34: 2,
  35: 2,
  36: 2,
  37: 2,
  38: 2,
  39: 2,
  40: 2,
  41: 2,
  42: 2,
  43: 2,
  44: 2,
  45: 2,
  46: 2,
  47: 2,
  48: 2,
  49: 2,
  50: 2,
  51: 2,
  52: 2},
 'year_nb': {0: 2017,
  1: 2017,
  2: 2017,
  3: 2017,
  4: 2017,
  5: 2017,
  6: 2017,
  7: 2018,
  8: 2018,
  9: 2018,
  10: 2018,
  11: 2018,
  12: 2018,
  13: 2018,
  14: 2019,
  15: 2019,
  16: 2019,
  17: 2019,
  18: 2019,
  19: 2019,
  20: 2019,
  21: 2020,
  22: 2020,
  23: 2020,
  24: 2020,
  25: 2020,
  26: 2020,
  27: 2020,
  28: 2017,
  29: 2017,
  30: 2017,
  31: 2017,
  32: 2017,
  33: 2017,
  34: 2017,
  35: 2018,
  36: 2018,
  37: 2018,
  38: 2018,
  39: 2018,
  40: 2018,
  41: 2018,
  42: 2019,
  43: 2019,
  44: 2019,
  45: 2019,
  46: 2019,
  47: 2019,
  48: 2019,
  49: 2020,
  50: 2020,
  51: 2020,
  52: 2020},
 'start_date': {0: datetime.date(2017, 1, 2),
  1: datetime.date(2017, 1, 3),
  2: datetime.date(2017, 1, 4),
  3: datetime.date(2017, 1, 5),
  4: datetime.date(2017, 1, 6),
  5: datetime.date(2017, 1, 7),
  6: datetime.date(2017, 1, 8),
  7: datetime.date(2018, 1, 1),
  8: datetime.date(2018, 1, 2),
  9: datetime.date(2018, 1, 3),
  10: datetime.date(2018, 1, 4),
  11: datetime.date(2018, 1, 5),
  12: datetime.date(2018, 1, 6),
  13: datetime.date(2018, 1, 7),
  14: datetime.date(2018, 12, 31),
  15: datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
  16: datetime.date(2019, 1, 2),
  17: datetime.date(2019, 1, 3),
  18: datetime.date(2019, 1, 4),
  19: datetime.date(2019, 1, 5),
  20: datetime.date(2019, 1, 6),
  21: datetime.date(2019, 12, 30),
  22: datetime.date(2019, 12, 31),
  23: datetime.date(2020, 1, 1),
  24: datetime.date(2020, 1, 2),
  25: datetime.date(2020, 1, 3),
  26: datetime.date(2020, 1, 4),
  27: datetime.date(2020, 1, 5),
  28: datetime.date(2017, 1, 9),
  29: datetime.date(2017, 1, 10),
  30: datetime.date(2017, 1, 11),
  31: datetime.date(2017, 1, 12),
  32: datetime.date(2017, 1, 13),
  33: datetime.date(2017, 1, 14),
  34: datetime.date(2017, 1, 15),
  35: datetime.date(2018, 1, 8),
  36: datetime.date(2018, 1, 9),
  37: datetime.date(2018, 1, 10),
  38: datetime.date(2018, 1, 11),
  39: datetime.date(2018, 1, 12),
  40: datetime.date(2018, 1, 13),
  41: datetime.date(2018, 1, 14),
  42: datetime.date(2019, 1, 7),
  43: datetime.date(2019, 1, 8),
  44: datetime.date(2019, 1, 9),
  45: datetime.date(2019, 1, 10),
  46: datetime.date(2019, 1, 11),
  47: datetime.date(2019, 1, 12),
  48: datetime.date(2019, 1, 13),
  49: datetime.date(2020, 1, 6),
  50: datetime.date(2020, 1, 7),
  51: datetime.date(2020, 1, 8),
  52: datetime.date(2020, 1, 9)},
 'hour_duration': {0: 61.0,
  1: 83.5,
  2: 79.5,
  3: 108.0,
  4: 128.0,
  5: 93.5,
  6: 43.0,
  7: 89.75,
  8: 201.75,
  9: 208.75,
  10: 292.25,
  11: 484.75,
  12: 349.0,
  13: 115.25,
  14: 616.9166666666666,
  15: 191.21666666666667,
  16: 435.9166666666667,
  17: 456.49999999999994,
  18: 510.91666666666663,
  19: 480.91666666666663,
  20: 424.5,
  21: 896.7500000000002,
  22: 1315.0,
  23: 595.1666666666667,
  24: 902.0,
  25: 1046.25,
  26: 770.5,
  27: 722.25,
  28: 146.0,
  29: 210.5,
  30: 141.25,
  31: 150.75,
  32: 177.5,
  33: 85.0,
  34: 35.0,
  35: 375.91666666666663,
  36: 497.41666666666663,
  37: 511.66666666666663,
  38: 523.0,
  39: 546.75,
  40: 328.5,
  41: 224.0,
  42: 561.6666666666667,
  43: 698.0833333333333,
  44: 884.5,
  45: 1109.0,
  46: 1111.1666666666667,
  47: 607.9166666666667,
  48: 529.9166666666667,
  49: 682.0,
  50: 862.2069091666667,
  51: 743.7139494444444,
  52: 992.0}}
```

Comment: Does `df.groupby(['week_nb', 'year_nb'].agg({'hour_duration': 'sum'})` not work?

Comment: Could you remove the images and also include sample code that has failed? Perhaps share data as a dict using `pandas`' `to_dict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['week_nb','year_nb']).agg({'start_date':'min','hour_duration':'sum'})
```

Result:

```
                 start_date  hour_duration
week_nb year_nb                           
1       2017     2017-01-02     596.500000
        2018     2018-01-01    1741.500000
        2019     2018-12-31    3116.883333
        2020     2019-12-30    6247.916667
2       2017     2017-01-09     946.000000
        2018     2018-01-08    3007.250000
        2019     2019-01-07    5502.250000
        2020     2020-01-06    3279.920859
```

That said, switching week and year do make more sense to me:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['year_nb','week_nb']).agg({'start_date':'min','hour_duration':'sum'})
                 start_date  hour_duration
year_nb week_nb                           
2017    1        2017-01-02     596.500000
        2        2017-01-09     946.000000
2018    1        2018-01-01    1741.500000
        2        2018-01-08    3007.250000
2019    1        2018-12-31    3116.883333
        2        2019-01-07    5502.250000
2020    1        2019-12-30    6247.916667
        2        2020-01-06    3279.920859
```